# Is is possible to set options in a SnowSQL config file?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I know I can do:

```
snowsql --connection my_connection --option friendly=false
```

But I'd like to do:

```
[connections.my_connection]
accountname = aa12345.us-central1.gcp
username = my_username
password = my_password
warehouse = my_warehouse
role = my_role
option = friendly=false
```

The above yields:

```
Error parsing /home/me/.snowsql/config Recovering partially parsed config values: cause: Parsing failed with several errors.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in your home directory find .snowsql sub-directory, inside is a config file you can set set exactly that!

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql-config.html#snowsql-config-file

Comment: It's under this section: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql-config.html#configuration-options-section. And one cannot set different options for different connections.

Comment: you can set multiple connections, and call it in the CLI command

nowsql -c au_demo -o log_level=DEBUG -o log_file=./debug.log -f /load_dv.sql

au_demo refers to the connection i want to use

Comment: Thank you, Patrick. What I was hoping for was snowsql -c au_demo would give a log_level of DEBUG and snowsql -c other_demo would give a log_level of INFO, for example.